# How can I generate a set of (short) unique identifiers which are easy to check but hard to spoof?

Tags: algorithm, security

For example, such as the license keys much software uses. I had thought of cryptographically signing a sequence, so I could have maybe 4 bytes for the ID and say 8 bytes for the signature, but I can't find a suitable algorithm.

What I need is something that an attacker can't readily generate, but which is stored in less than approx 20 ASCII bytes. I also need to be confident of uniqueness. This doesn't need to be completely secure, only secure against a casual attack.

Note: I'm doing this in java on appengine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just generate a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid) for each ID and keep track of the ones you've generated in a database. The universe of GUIDs is so large that each will be unique. It's not cryptographic so there's a possibility that anyone who has a large enough population of your generated ones could produce a match, but I think the odds are still miniscule.

A GUID is 128 bits, which can be encoded in 23 bytes using [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). You will probably need to ensure uniqueness manually though.

Comment: Can this be done in a small number of bytes? Smaller is better as I'll be using these in QR codes...

Comment: @RichardRussell the length of HMAC is the same as length of the underlying hash e.g. 128 bit for MD5 (32 bytes in hex, 24 bytes in base64, you probably can't just use the 16 bytes binary representation). If you need to somehow identify keys you also need to attach your ID to it.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the values including the id into a string and use the byte based HDMAC with a secret key and max length. Just make sure that you have a unique part in the values to encrypt. This could be server time or some other ID. The length will need to be tested that it remains within your 20 character requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption is reversible, so the output is guaranteed unique for unique inputs.  Just encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. using the same key every time.  For 128 bit output use AES and 128 bit numbers in ECB mode.  Other modes will need identical IV/Nonces as well.  For 64 bit numbers use DES.  For other size numbers either use Hasty Pudding cypher or roll your own simple Feistel cypher for the size you want.

ECB is not the most secure mode, but I do not get the impression that you are looking for very high levels of security here.